# protected destructor with unique_ptr

Tags: c++

I am trying to call APIs from a third party library.

There is a trouble when I want to use unique_ptr with a class having protected destructor.

Here is the example,

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent {  
  public:  
    Parent () //Constructor
    {
        cout << "\n Parent constructor called\n" << endl;
    }
  protected:
    ~ Parent() //Dtor
    {
        cout << "\n Parent destructor called\n" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent 
{
  public:
    Child () //Ctor
    {
        cout << "\nChild constructor called\n" << endl;
    }
    ~Child() //dtor
    {
        cout << "\nChild destructor called\n" << endl;
    }
};

Parent* get() {
  return new Child();
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  Parent * p1 = get(); // this is ok
  std::unique_ptr<Parent> p2(get()); // this is not ok
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to use unique_ptr with Parent class. But the compiler threw the errors

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation 
of ‘void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const 
[with _Tp = Parent]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:236:17:   required 
from ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp 
= Parent; _Dp = std::default_delete<Parent>]’
main.cpp:38:35:   required from here
main.cpp:12:5: error: ‘Parent::~Parent()’ is protected
 ~ Parent() //Dtor
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:81:0,
             from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:76:2: error: within 
this context
  delete __ptr;
```

Any idea about getting rid of this issue? I can't hack Parent and Child class since they are the classes of the third party library.

Comment: You are not allowed to delete through a Parent pointer, unique_ptr or shared_ptr or raw ptr. This is an enforced design decision of the library authors. Not an oversight, not a coincidence. They are actively and deliberately preventing you from doing this. Whether this is a good design choice or not I cannot tell, but it's there.

Comment: @n.m. To be fair, from this question we have no way of knowing whether it was deliberate or not. It could just be a terrible bug! Weirdly, in [the OP's previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56240230/560648) (which _seems_ to be about the same problem), the base destructor is `virtual`, and [the library author's design does not appear to ignore any of these considerations](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html). Suppose the OP could have moved on to some other library since last week....

Comment: (And if it _is_ that library, [the answer is right there in the docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#non-public-destructors)!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes it coild be a bug if OP is the only user of the library. Otherwise it would get fixed. I'm not sure what you mean by *that* library. This code is not a part of PyBind11.

Comment: @n.m.: I interpreted this question as being an abstracted/MCVE version of the real code (which in turn I assume, perhaps wrongly, is using PyBind11). Do we think the third-party library really has classes named `Parent` and `Child`?

Comment: @n.m.: _"yes it coild be a bug if OP is the only user of the library. Otherwise it would get fixed"_ By that logic, no software/library used by two or more people worldwide would have any bugs!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit there are "2*2==3.999999998" bugs, and then there are "2*2 doesn't compile" bugs.

Comment: @n.m.: [A missing virtual destructor usually doesn't cause a compilation failure.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3bf5266064c660b) I say "usually" because it's UB so I need to hedge my bets but, in fact, I've _never_ witnessed such a thing nor can I imagine how a compiler would be able to diagnose it in general. This sort of bug is actually quite easy to miss.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A missing virtual destructor usually doesn't cause a compilation failure, but a protected one does, and this is exactly the failure we are seeing here.

Comment: @n.m. Hah, right, I'll give you that. Though (again making a wild assumption about the real code) the lib does actually permit this and give the programmer the tools to do it (see links)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make `std::default_delete<Parent>` a friend of `Parent` to fix that error. And you may also like to make `~Parent` `virtual` to avoid undefined behaviour when `delete`ing a derived class through `Parent` pointer.

E.g.:

```
class Parent { 
    friend std::default_delete<Parent>;
    // ...
protected:
    virtual ~Parent();
    // ...
```

---

However, `Parent` design makes it clear that you are not supposed to `delete` through `Parent` pointer, this is why the destructor is non-public. Read [Virtuality](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) for more details:

> Guideline #4: A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual.

---

You may like to introduce another intermediate base class to solve the issue:

```
class Parent { // Comes from a 3rd-party library header.
protected:
    ~Parent();
};

struct MyParent : Parent {  // The intermediate base class.
    virtual ~MyParent();
};

class Derived : public MyParent {};

std::unique_ptr<MyParent> createDerived() {
    return std::unique_ptr<MyParent>(new Derived);
}

int main() {
    auto p = createDerived();
}
```

Comment: Huh, nice! Simple and elegant :)

Comment: _"may also like to make"_ => are going to have to

Comment: I can't modify the parent class since it's a third party library.

Comment: @alec.tu In this case, you are not supposed to delete through `Parent` pointer, this is why the destructor is non-public.

Comment: `std::default_delete` is a `struct` in MSVC (2019), not a `class`, so `friend class` yields a warning. I just omitted the `class` completely, and MSVC was OK (will check GCC later).

Comment: @ddevienne Thank you for your comment, you are quite right, [since C++11 `friend` doesn't require `class` or `struct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend). Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the real way to get rid of this issue is to not derive classes from `Parent`, and to not manage the lifetime of `Parent` objects (or any derived classes) using `std::unique_ptr<Parent>`.

In other words, you need to redesign your classes.

The reasons I say this are

- If someone has gone to the trouble of giving `Parent` a protected non-virtual destructor, the intent is most likely to avoid having a `Parent *` which actually points at an instance of a derived class and is released using operator `delete`.  A library designer will not (normally) do this without good reason.
- Your code can be forced to compile as is (e.g. by making `std::default_delete<Parent>` a friend of `Parent`).   However, `std::default_delete` is used by `unique_ptr` to release the managed object.   And it uses operator `delete`.   That gives undefined behaviour if the object being managed by the `unique_ptr<Parent>` is of a type derived from `Parent`.

So, in short, you're working around the intent of (whoever designed) your third party library and, if you force the code to compile anyway, your reward will be undefined behaviour.